# Updating String title() for field in attribute table using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy

When using the title method, can it only be used on a string or can it run through an entire field and update Names to proper case in a table?

```
str.title()
```

I have tried the following and it did not work;

```
arcpy.title(table,'Field')
```

Comment: The only difference between this question and the duplicate seems to be that it uses `title` rather than `upper` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be used on table field/values that are data type string/text.  Use either Field Calculator, [Calculate Field](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-field.htm), or [arcpy da update cursor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm).

**eg. Field Calculator and Calculate Field:**

```
!myField!.title()
```

**eg. arcpy da update cursor:**

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, 'myFieldName') as cursor:
  for row in cursor:
    if row[0]:  # check for value
      row[0] = row[0].title()
      cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: When testing this script I get the following error                     
    row[0] = row[0].title()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'title'

Comment: @winscott68, I'm guessing it is because it is trying to perform the .title() method on a NULL value which is not a string.  I've updated my answer to check for this.